# How to retrieve rows based on a time interval within rows in Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have table (**t_answer**) like below:

| user_id | created_at | answer |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-01-01 | 1a |
| 1 | 2023-01-02 | 1b |
| 1 | 2023-01-11 | 1c |
| 2 | 2023-02-05 | 2a |
| 2 | 2023-02-20 | 2a |

I want to retrieve the rows within an interval of 1 week starting from each user's first answer's `created_at` date. So, the result will be like:

| user_id | created_at | answer |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-01-01 | 1a |
| 1 | 2023-01-02 | 1b |
| 2 | 2023-02-05 | 2a |

So, what should be the query to get this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a subquery:

```
select t.* from t_answer t where t.created_at <= (select min(t1.created_at) 
   from t_answer t1 where t1.user_id = t.user_id) + interval '1 week';
```

[See fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/5RGODOO_).

Answer (score 1):

```
with t as
    (select
        row_number() over (partition by user_id order by created_at) as rn,
        *
        from t_answer)
select
    o.*
    from t
        join t_answer as o on
            t.user_id = o.user_id
    where t.rn = 1 and
        o.created_at < t.created_at + interval '1 week';
```